# Filtering a large Pandas DataFrame based on a list of strings in column names

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Stack Overflow Family,

I have recently started learning Python and am using Pandas to handle some factory data. The csv file is essentially a large dataframe (1621 rows × 5633 columns). While I need all the rows as these are data of each unit, I need to filter many unwanted columns. I have identified a list of strings in these column names that I can use to find only the wanted columns, however, I am not able to figure out what a good logic here would be or any built in python functions.

`dropna` is not an option for me as some of these wanted columns have NA as values (for example test limit)
dropna for columns with all `NA` is also not good enough as I will still end up with a large number of columns.

Looking for some guidance here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please show sample input Dataframe with expected output for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Given the time complexity of my previous solution, I came up with a way to use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", "mango"]
app = ["app", "ban"]
new_list = [x for x in fruits if any(y in x for y in app)]
```

output:
`['apple', 'banana']`

This should only display the columns you need. In your case you just need to do:

```
my_strings = ["A", "B", ...]
new_list = [x for x in df.columns if any(y in x for y in my_strings)]
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, @roshshetty. This would not work for me as the wanted column names are just part of the string, not the entire column names. Having the entire column name is not feasible as these names are always changing, hence just part of the string.

Comment: Could you give a brief example in terms of your data as to what you are trying to say?

Comment: Sure, @roshshetty. We can forget the rows as I need all of them. These are all numbers I will have to use to plot Cpk, distribution etc. For columns, as an example, I have strings such as Tester, Test Station, Test Initialization, Test Initialization Cycle Time, SW flash,  SW flash Cycle Time Battery Charging, Battery Charging Cycle Time, Battery Charging Retry, etc. In this example, I would only need Battery Charging column and need to filter out the rest. Of course, I have more such columns, which is why I put the keywords in a list.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say now. I made the necessary edits for the post which would fit the criteria you are talking about. If I am still misunderstanding it, you can correct me.

Comment: This solution works for my case, it also handles the unique scenario I have run into that may need some additional handling in regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of valid columns you can just use `df.filter(cols_subset, axis=1)` to drop everything else.
You could use a regex to also match substrings from your list in column names:

```
df.filter(regex='|'.join(cols_subset), axis=1)
```

Or you could match only columns starting with a substring from your list:

```
df.filter(regex='^('+'|'.join(cols_subset)+')', axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried the filter option, but could not do what I intended to since I was using a list. Need to dig deeper into regex operation, thank you @filippo

Comment: Thank you, @filippo. Your explanation is perfect and I used it to filter down my dataset. I understand regex a bit more now, still a noob at Python - so learning the art of writing efficient code.

Comment: Wanted to update something I observed that does mess up my selections. Hopefully there is a way around while still using regex. Here is what I see: Four of my column names are 6.3 Adjacent -10MHz, 6.3 Adjacent +10MHz, 6.3 Adjacent  -7.5MHz, 6.3 Adjacent  +7.5MHz. Using regex, it does not seem to differentiate between columns -10MHz and +10MHz and instead jumps to -7.5MHz after -10MHz. This results in fewer columns than what I am expecting to see. Any thoughts of how I can handle this scenario ?    PS: roshshetty solution worked as expected, verified it.

Comment: @VinayGHegde no problem, go with the solution that actually solves your problem ;-) I would need to see which substring you are trying to match to understand what's wrong.

Comment: I am actually using the entire name as the string to match for these four columns (Some of the other columns have longer names, for which I use a substring)

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly the column names, what you could do is some thing like that:

```
unwanted_cols = ['col1', 'col4'] #list of unwanted cols names

df_cleaned = current_df.drop(unwanted_cols, axis=1)

# or 

current_df.drop(unwanted_cols, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

If you don't know exactly the columns names what you could do is first retrieveing all the columns

`all_cols = current_df.columns.tolist()`

and apply a regex on all of the columns names, to obtain all of the columns names that matches your list of string and apply the same code as above

Comment: Thank you @Netim. I do have the list of all the column names like you suggested. But I am not sure to proceed from here to filter them based on the list of strings I can use. How do I use regex if I have a list of strings (which just a part of the name of wanted columns)

Comment: as @Venkat suggested you could do something like this `regex_rule_from_list='|'.join(your_string_list)` and then use `df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(regex_rule_from_list)], axis=1)`

Comment: I will definitely try this soon, want to learn more about regex now!

Answer (score 0):

You can drop columns from a dataframe by applying string contains with regular expression. Below is an example
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('^abc')], axis=1)

Comment: Thank you, @Venkat. If I want to use your example, then is it possible to apply regular expression on a list of strings that I have identified ?

Comment: Yes, you can prepare a regular expression and check whether it is matching your columns here @ https://regex101.com/ or any similar website

You can apply this logic on any sample data frame and check the result., Good luck

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but I will certainly give this a shot to understand how this works. Thank you.